# Why is the value of the select field getting added to the remaining fields in the form

Tags: css, reactjs

When I have selected a value from the select tag it the selected value is getting added to the remaining fields. This was the error :- [This was what happened

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './C.css';
import {ButtonToolbar,Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from 'axios';
export default class Coldata extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: 'select dept'};  
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.state={
          Regdno:'',
          Yos:'',
          dept:'',
          complaint:''
        };
      }

      onChange = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.Regdno)
        // Because we named the inputs to match their corresponding values in state, it's
        // super easy to update the state
        const state = this.state
        // console.log(e.target.value)
        state[e.target.Regdno] = e.target.value;
        this.setState(state);
      }

      onSubmit = (e) => {
        //   console.log("entered")
        e.preventDefault();
        // console.log(this.state)
        // get our form data out of state
        const data = this.state;
          axios.post('http://localhost:80/create/complaint', data) 
          .then((result) => {
            
            //access the results here....
            alert("Complaint created")
                // console.log(result)
          })
        
        
        // console.log(this.state)
        
      }

      handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
      }

    render() {
      const{Regdno,Yos,dept,complaint}=this.state;

        return (            
    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}  className="col" >
 <div align="right"><Button bsSize="large" href="/login"  value="Logout"> Logout </Button></div>
    <font size="5" >
  <div className="log">
  <h1> College </h1>
  <p> Regd_no </p>
  <input type="text" name="Regdno" id="regdno" size="10" placeholder="Enter Regd_no" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange} required />
  <p> Year of study </p>
  <input type="text" name="Yos " size="5" placeholder="Enter year of study" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange} />
  <label> Select Dept </label>
 <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} className="op" name="dept" id="dept" required>
    <option value="Cse">Cse</option>
  <option value="Ece">Ece</option>
  <option value="It">IT</option>
  <option value="EEE">EEE</option>
   <option value="Mech">Mech</option>
   <option value="Chem">Chem</option>
  </select>  
  <br />
  <label> Disciplinary Issue </label>
  <input type="text" size="20" name="complaint" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange}  required/>
  <ButtonToolbar>
      <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="lg" type="submit" value="submit" block> ADD </Button>
    </ButtonToolbar>
   
          </div>
          </font>
        </form>
        );
      }
    }
```

```css
.col{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: url(./Nature.jpeg);
 background-size: contain;
 background-position: center;
 font-family: sans-serief;
 height: 768px
}
.log{
 width: 320px;
 height:570px;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 color: #fff;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 70px 30px;
}
h1{
 margin:0;
 padding: 0 0 10px;
 position: relative;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:22px;
}
.log p{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-weight:bold;
}
.log input{
 width:100%;
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
.log input[type="text"],input[type="password"] :focus
{
 border:none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
 background:transparent;
 outline:none;
 height:60 px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 22px;
 box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.log input[type="submit"]
{
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  background: #1c8adb;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.op {
 margin-top: 10px;
 width:auto;
 color: red;
 height: 40px;
}
```

[image]

A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

Comment: Its because you have written  'value={this.state.value} ' with each input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove  `value={this.state.value}` and  `onChange={this.onChange}`  from the  input `type="text"` elements.

Comment: If i removed the the values were not accepted by form

Comment: if i entered the value the value was not getting displayed

Comment: When i entered all the values in the form it should get stored in the database

Comment: Now i have changed the function of the select component it works fine

Comment: Thanks for the answer